# jquery still need to hide form field if backend validation fails

Tags: jquery

I'm using the below Jquery to only show a form field with the css class `.time` if the value of a select in an earlier form field is `False` (python backend). (It's hidden is the select has a null value `false` or if the user selects `True`).

That works fine, but the issue is if the form fails validation and the user has selected `False` the field with `.time` stays hidden after the page refreshes.

How can I not only `hide()` or `show` the element depending on a `change` event but also dependant on a value? (ie so after page refresh if the value is `False` then it will also display the field)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_same_address').on('change',  function (e){
      var timeAtAddress = $(this).val()
      console.log(timeAtAddress)
      if (timeAtAddress === 'False' ){
        $('.time').show()
      }
      if (timeAtAddress === 'True' || timeAtAddress === false){
        $('.time').hide()
      }
    })
  })
```

Just trying the to grab the select value, failed to work for some reason?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var timeAtAddress = $('#id_same_address').val()
  console.log(timeAtAddress)
  if (timeAtAddress === 'False') {
    $('.time').show()
  }
  if (timeAtAddress === 'True' || timeAtAddress === false) {
    $('.time').hide()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me. Keep in mind that you need to set the option as selected (default) in order for the field to be set correctly when document ready fires.

Example:
http://jsbin.com/nopenohomo/edit?html,js,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    let dropdown_value = $('#dropdown').val();

    if (dropdown_value === 'true') {
      $('.time').show();
    } else {
      $('.time').hide();
    }

    $('#dropdown').on('change',  function (e){
      var timeAtAddress = $(this).val()
      console.log(timeAtAddress)
      if (timeAtAddress === 'true' ){
        $('.time').show()
      }
      if (timeAtAddress === 'false'){
        $('.time').hide()
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
 <select id="dropdown">
  <option value="true">True</option>
  <option value="false" selected="false">False</option>
</select> 
  <div class="time">
    Test
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```